# Get the complete url in browser in php with "#" in the url

Tags: php, url, get, request

I have a page that serves a link like this:

`example.com/#/media/ArCGasGRs`

I want to get the url "example.com/#/media/ArCGasGRs" complete in PHP.

I try:

`$SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`

It's return me only "/" .All the string after "#" is missing and that is that i want.

There is a way to get that kind of url?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web browsers will prevent the server-side from reading anything after the # fragment for security reason (in-short the browser does not not include the fragment in the request). You will need to use this on the the client-side (JavaScript like AJAX or AngularJS) to make async request and bind your data